# Playmode running at really low Fps

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, rendering, render, frame-rate

I just realized that in the editor during the playmode my game is running at ~30 fps even with empty scene, and if i try to target fps at 200 for example it stay at 30 fps. Even then before in other projects my games was able to reach even 200 fps. What is going wrong in this project? Maybe some default settings?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html
this ?

Comment: I know unity documentation and it's not helpful but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a little bit and found this post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/7lbx0t/fix_for_low_fps_in_play_mode/. Basically, your Windows Defender maybe scan everytime you launch playmode. So, if you add an exclusion for it, maybe it could help.

Comment: Hi Philou, i tried to remove Unity process from window defender but it looks not working. I suspected that the problem could be with the nvidia settings but even disabling the whisper mode doesn't work!